# Get variable inside certain div with jquery, when there are multiple divs with same id

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, jsp

I'm printing an arraylist with jsp. Each object inside of that arraylist is printed with a loop like this:

```
                        <% ArrayList <MessageObject> list = (ArrayList<MessageObject>) request.getAttribute("list"); %>


                                <%int index = 0;%>
                                <%for(MessageObject msg :list){
                                    index++;
                                    if(mensaje.getState().compareTo("unread") == 0){%>
                                    <tr data-status="unread" class="unread">
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="javascript:;" class="star">
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="media">
                                                <h4 class="title">
                                                            User Identifier
                                                </h4>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>                                        
                                        <td id="unread-id">      
                                                <div class="media">
                                                    <p class="summary"><% out.print(msg.getMessage());%></p>

                                                    <input id="index" type="text" value="<%out.print(index);%>"></input>

                                                </div>
```

Some of the closing tags and other structures are not written above, in order to make my code easier to read.
Basically that prints me messages from a queue, and its index in the arraylist:
[image]

My problem is that I want to save the index value of any of my messages when I click on them.

I tried this:

```
<script>
      $(document).on('click', '#unread-id', function () {
          var index = $('#index').val();
          $("#setindex").val(index);
       });
```

So I click on any div containing a message, the script is called, but I always get the same index value, 1.
Problem is that having always the same div with the same id name, causes that my script always selects the first div with id unread-id, which is always the first one, so it returns 1.

How can I get the index of the clicked div, if all my container divs have the same id value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to your `<td id="unread-id">` like `row` and change your script for the following one. Your `td` should end up looking like `<td class="row">`. Also, don't use ids in your inputs, change it to a class, like `row-input`.

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.row', function () {
      var index = $(this).find('.row-input').val();
      $("#setindex").val(index);
});
```

**JSP Changes**

- `<td id="unread-id">` to `<td class="row">`
- `<input id="index" type="text" value="<%out.print(index);%>"></input>` to `<input class="row-input" type="text" value="<%out.print(index);%>"></input>`

**Note**

You are setting the same `id` to all your rows. An id must be unique and that is the reason you keep getting the same index.

Answer (score 1):

First - id should be unique in your page. You should really fix this (and if you need some selector to work with multiple elements - you can use classname instead).

However - your code can work (might cause issues with some browsers, so I really advise you to fix this asap):

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#unread-id', function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="unread-id" value="1" /><br />
<input id="unread-id" value="2" /><br />
<input id="unread-id" value="3" /><br />
<input id="unread-id" value="4" /><br />
```

When inside the `click` function - the `this` element is the element you just clicked. You can use that in order to get the value that you need.

Comment: Well, `id` should be unique. That is already a bit of an issue.

Comment: @AlainCruz completely agree with you, and it's mentioned in my answer. However - even in that case - this will work (in current browsers). The solution might not work in the future, so I really advise to use class instead of duplicate the id all over the page.

Comment: and btw - your usage if `$(this)` after you read my answer is not so nice :)

Comment: You know, I only saw the first duplicated id in his `td`, until I realized there was another in his `input` hahaha :-)

Comment: If you based your solution on someone else's answer - at lease have the courtesy of upvote their answer...

Comment: Well I am upvoting, because you did show it. Still, yours is missing the td's `id` issue, which he/she should fix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183522/discussion-between-alain-cruz-and-dekel).